# How to use dotted line to make indentation clearer in algorithmicx?

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I wish to indicate clearly when a block starts and ends with "enclosing lines" in addition to the indentation.

I understand that I can do it with `algorithm2e` like so

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \SetLine % For v3.9
 %\SetAlgoLined % For previous releases [?]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

rendering as
[image]

However now, I am **using `algorithmicx`. How may I achieve the same effect?**